# Non-static method view::load_views() should not be called statically with VIEWS

Tags: views, 6

When I copied my Drupal 6 web site to another server with a higher version ofPHP, I get this problem on all pages that have views:

```
strict warning: Non-static method view::load_views() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\all\modules\views\views.module on line 864.
strict warning: Non-static method view::db_objects() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\all\modules\views\includes\view.inc on line 1417.
strict warning: Declaration of calendar_plugin_display_page::options_submit() should be compatible with views_plugin::options_submit(&$form, &$form_state) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\all\modules\calendar\includes\calendar_plugin_display_page.inc on line 297.
strict warning: Declaration of calendar_plugin_display_page::options() should be compatible with views_object::options() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\all\modules\calendar\includes\calendar_plugin_display_page.inc on line 297.
strict warning: Declaration of calendar_plugin_display_block::options() should be compatible with views_object::options() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\all\modules\calendar\includes\calendar_plugin_display_block.inc on line 78.
strict warning: Declaration of calendar_plugin_display_attachment::options_submit() should be compatible with views_plugin::options_submit(&$form, &$form_state) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\all\modules\calendar\includes\calendar_plugin_display_attachment.inc on line 242.
strict warning: Declaration of calendar_plugin_display_attachment::options() should be compatible with views_object::options() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\all\modules\calendar\includes\calendar_plugin_display_attachment.inc on line 242.
strict warning: Declaration of calendar_plugin_display_ical::options_submit() should be compatible with views_plugin::options_submit(&$form, &$form_state) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\all\modules\calendar\calendar_ical\calendar_plugin_display_ical.inc on line 217.
strict warning: Declaration of views_content_plugin_display_panel_pane::options_submit() should be compatible with views_plugin::options_submit(&$form, &$form_state) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\all\modules\ctools\views_content\plugins\views\views_content_plugin_display_panel_pane.inc on line 40
```

Answer (score 4):

These errors, at least those coming from Views, does not really have a proper solution, because the versions of Views and Calendar that cause them, are no longer being updated.

Views 2 is officially not being updated anymore, and I doubt anything but serious security problems is going to change that. Calendar could potentially have the problem fixed, but this is also a module with a great deal of issues, and for an old version, I simply wouldn't expect these problems to be prioritized enough to get fixed.

Your basic options:

1. Upgrade to Views 3, and the corresponding Calendar version.
2. Disable E_STRICT error reporting.
3. Simply accept that the errors are there.

A more sophisticated and perhaps better solution would be to locate the relevant patches in the issue queues, and apply them in your drush make file.

Answer (score 0):

This is [issue 465332 on d.o](https://www.drupal.org/node/465332), part of the Views issue queue. There's a patch attached that's supposed to work but the patch is actually patching core.

For me personally I'm just disabling error reporting to the screen at `admin/settings/error-reporting`. This is a good enough solution since I'm not doing any serious work on my D6 sites anymore.

Answer (score -3):

goto

administer -> settings -> error handling

set: Error reporting: to write errors to the log

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question here?

Comment: This issue was marked as non fix. It is recommended that onscreen notices are disabled on production environments.